# EF code first update is not working for one to many relationship

Tags: ef-code-first

The EF code first update is not working for one to many relationship

I have 2 entities

```
   // Save
    public class Person 
    {    
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string Name{ get; set; } 
        public virtual List<Email> Emails { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Email 
    { 
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public int PersonId { get; set; } 
    public virtual Person person { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; } 
    }

EFContext context = new EFContext(); 
    Person person; 
    Email email;

    person = new Person(); 
    person.Name = "Rocky"; 

    person.Emails = new List<Email>(); 
    email = new Email { EmailAddress = "rocky@frostbitefalls.com" }; 
    person.Emails.Add(email); 
    email = new Email { EmailAddress = "rocky@squirrel.com" }; 
    person.Emails.Add(email); 

    context.People.Add(person); 
    context.SaveChanges();

// Update
person = new Person(); 
person.Id=1;
    person.Name = "Rocky Altered"; 

    person.Emails = new List<Email>(); 
    email = new Email {Id=1, EmailAddress = "Altered_rocky@frostbitefalls.com" }; 
    person.Emails.Add(email); 
    email = new Email {Id=2, EmailAddress = "Altered_rocky@squirrel.com" }; 
    person.Emails.Add(email);

UpdatePerson(person);

public bool UpdatePerson(Person entity)
{
var updatePerson = GetPersonById(entity.Id);
updatePerson.Name=entity.Name;
updatePerson.Emails=entity.Emails;

    DataContext.Entry<Person>(updatePerson).State = EntityState.Modified;
DataContext.SaveChanges();
DataContext.Entry<Person>(updatePerson).Reload();
}
```

The person with 2 email addresses are saving properly but while updating the email address of the inserted person is not working.

Comment: What err it is throwing at you?

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
 public class Person 
{    
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name{ get; set; } 
    public List<Email> Emails { get; set; } 
}

public class Email 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } //This will generate PKey.
    public virtual Person person { get; set; } //This will create the FKey.
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that you need to apply a ForeignKeyAttribute to any FK you explicitly include:

```
    public class Person 
    {    
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string Name{ get; set; } 
        public virtual List<Email> Emails { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Email 
    { 
        public int Id { get; set; } 

        [ForeignKey("Person")]
        public int PersonId { get; set; } 
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

        public string EmailAddress { get; set; } 
    }
```

By applying that attribute you tell EF Migrations to use "PersonId" as the FK column name for the "Person" relationship. The rest should work as-is.